# node.js access json object issue

Tags: javascript, json

i find that it is interesting in the follwoing node.js program, when i try to access JSON object's property, the only way to access it is to access like an array, not like a class (object name followed by period and property name), and I don't know why.

here is the code:

```
    var users={
    'tobi': 'foo',
    'cobi': 'foo2',
    'nobi': 'foo3'
   };

  var connect = require('connect');
  var app = connect()
  .use(connect.basicAuth(function(user, pass){
    console.log(users.tobi);  //foo
    console.log(users['tobi']); //foo
    console.log(user+'----'+pass); //tobi----foo
    console.log(users);   //{ tobi: 'foo', cobi: 'foo2', nobi: 'foo3' }
    console.log(users.user); //undefined, why?
    console.log(users[user]);  //foo         
    return users.user== pass;  //false of cause, but  return users[user]==pass  is true
   }))
 .use(function(req,res){
    res.end('you are logged in \n');
  });
 app.listen(3000);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaScript, the following two are equivalent:

- `x.y`
- `x['y']`

That means when you check `users.user` you're checking `users['user']` and not `users[user]`. Since your object doesn't have the key named `'user'`, it returns `undefined`.

Comment: you are right. so if a variable 'user' represents object 'users's property, there is no way to access 'users''s property like a class. it can only be access like an array.